# integration between Twilio chatbot and Airtable

Tags: twilio, airtable, make.com

I created Whatsapp chatbot in Twilio studio.
I need to send datas to Airtable, by using integromat.
Which kind of integration do i need to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Since you are already using Twilio Studio, then I would suggest you combine the [webhook](https://www.integromat.com/en/templates/gateway) and [Airtable](https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/airtable) integrations. You can trigger the Integromat webhook from a [Twilio Studio HTTP widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request) and then have the webhook integration update your Airtable.

Alternatively, as Alan has pointed out, you could use a Twilio Function to directly interact with the Airtable API and skip using Integromat completely.

Answer (score -1):

You can integrate with Airtable directly using their API's, as detailed in these two blogs. Airtable makes it very simple.

[Using Airtable as a database for your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/airtable-database-read)

[Writing to Airtable from your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/writing-airtable-sms)